# Compact Framework 2.0 compatibility with .Net Framework 4.0

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, compact-framework

Our application has a device side piece and a server side piece. We are upgrading the server projects to VS 2010 and .Net Framework 4.0. 
The device side applications will have to remain on compact framework 2.0 as VS 2010 does not support compact framework. 
My question is : will the device side compact framework 2.0 assemblies be able to talk with the server side assmeblies after they are upgraded to .net 4.0 ?

Comment: To be more specific; what is your comms protocol here?

Answer (score 0):

If you use webservices or tcp connection or anything else to communicate, then there should be no problem. But if you link classes to your compact framework project from desktop project then just the code need to be compatible so it can compile. Otherwise there is no reason why it should not work. You can event update to 3.5 compact framework to get more language features.